# What causes fetishes? Are they sexual disorders?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology, sexuality

Why do people have fetishes,  such as foot fetishes?
How do such fetishes form?
Are childhood incidents the main cause of fetishes?
Are fetishes a sexual disorder?

Answer (score 4):

Having one or more fetishes is very widespread, and thus rather normal.

> The prevalence of fetishism is not known with certainty.[21] The
>   majority of fetishists are male.[21] **In a 2011 study, 30% of men
>   reported fetishistic fantasies**, and 24.5% had engaged in fetishistic
>   acts. Of those reporting fantasies, 45% said the fetish was intensely
>   sexually arousing.[23] **In a 2014 study, 26.3% of women and 27.8% of
>   men acknowledged any fantasies about "having sex with a fetish or
>   non-sexual object"**.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_fetishism

A disorder is per definiton something **abnormal**

> disorder [dis-or´der] a derangement or abnormality of function;
>   http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/disorder

So the answer to your question would per definition be: **No. Having fetishes is normal and not a disorder.**

Comment: But abnormality is not enough, right? Or we can assume people with very high IQ to have a disorder (well, they can have, and these parameters can even be correlated; yet, having high IQ alone is not a disorder).